# Does FeathersJS use the Mongo Oplog for "live data" (when Mongodb is the database)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, feathersjs

The documentation is not very clear as to what mechanism is used. I only can find some references to pub/sub using a special collection in Mongo. If that is the case then this is a possible issue in more mixed environments when for example data is collected from other services using PHP or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feathers real-time functionality is added at the service level. It is database independent and the real-time mechanism works with any backend but to get real-time updates everything has to go through the Feathers REST or websocket API. So as long as e.g. a PHP backend talks to the Feathers REST API all clients will get real-time updates. If you put it directly in the database it won't.

A good example for that is this graphic I made to illustrate how you could make an existing API real-time. The Feathers services just proxies requests but all clients connected via websockets get real-time updates:

[image: Feathers API proxy]

Comment: In addition to this we will have oplog tailing support for some databases soon!